# Bitshifting and Rotating in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

For school we are making code for an ALU. The code has to do a calculation with 1, 2 or 3 inputs and copy it to the output, the calculation made is dependent on a 4 bit number.

The code I have is shown below, and the problem I have is that the `SSL` `SOL` `SRL` and `ROR` operators are not found:

> final_ex.vhd(34): can't determine definition of operator ""sll"" -- found 0 possible definitions
>
> final_ex.vhd(35): can't determine definition of operator ""rol"" -- found 0 possible definitions
>
> final_ex.vhd(36): can't determine definition of operator ""srl"" -- found 0 possible definitions
>
> final_ex.vhd(37): can't determine definition of operator ""ror"" -- found 0 possible definitions

My vdhl is on 2008, so it cant be version related. I have tried using `std_logic_vector` instead of `unsigned`, I have tried using a normal 4 bit number like "0101" but everytime there is the same error.
i tried diffrent datatypes but it wont work.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY final_ex IS
GENERIC(N: INTEGER:= 4); -- length of the inputs and output
  PORT(
    A, B: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
    functions: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    clock, Setflag, Zeroflag: IN STD_LOGIC;
    C: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE alu OF final_ex IS
  SIGNAL a_sig, b_sig: SIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL c_sig: SIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL c_unsig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL carry: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 1; 
  SIGNAL a_unsig: UNSIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
  a_unsig <= UNSIGNED(A);
  ---------Logic Unit----------- ( with unsigned output for logic, bitwise operators )
  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_unsig <=  A AND B     WHEN "000",
                    A OR B  WHEN "001",
                    A XOR B     WHEN "010",
                      NOT A     WHEN "011",
                    a_unsig SLL 1  WHEN "100",
                    a_unsig ROL 1  WHEN "101",
                    a_unsig SRL 1   WHEN "110",
                    a_unsig ROR 1   WHEN OTHERS;

  ---------- Arithmetic Unic:---------- ( signed for calcualtions with integers )
  a_sig <= SIGNED(A);
  b_sig <= SIGNED(B);
  carry <= 1 WHEN Setflag = '1' Else 0;

  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_sig <=     "0000"         WHEN "000",
                a_sig           WHEN "001",
                a_sig + 1   WHEN "010",
                a_sig - 1   WHEN "011",
                a_sig + b_sig   WHEN "100",
                a_sig + b_sig + carry   WHEN "101",
                a_sig - b_sig       WHEN "110",
                a_sig - b_sig - carry   WHEN OTHERS;

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WITH functions(3) SELECT
        c <=    c_unsig WHEN '1',
                STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_sig) WHEN OTHERS;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely the type of `c_unsig` is `std_logic_vector`. There are no predefined operators "sll", "rol", "srl" and "ror" with a signature [unsigned, integer return std_logic_vector] (where in the -2008 numeric_std package that unsigned would be the base type UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED).

There are three ways to fix this.

**With type conversion:**

```
  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_unsig <=  A AND B     WHEN "000",
                    A OR B  WHEN "001",
                    A XOR B     WHEN "010",
                      NOT A     WHEN "011",
                    std_logic_vector(a_unsig SLL 1)  WHEN "100",
                    std_logic_vector(a_unsig ROL 1)  WHEN "101",
                    std_logic_vector(a_unsig SRL 1)   WHEN "110",
                    std_logic_vector(a_unsig ROR 1)   WHEN OTHERS;
```

This relies on the signatures of the functions declared in package numeric_std.

**Changing the type of c_unsig:**

```
  SIGNAL c_unsig: unsigned(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL carry: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 1; 
  SIGNAL a_unsig: UNSIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
  a_unsig <= UNSIGNED(A);
  ---------Logic Unit----------- ( with unsigned output for logic, bitwise operators )
  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_unsig <=      unsigned (A AND B )    WHEN "000",
                    unsigned (A OR B)      WHEN "001",
                    unsigned (A XOR B)     WHEN "010",
                    unsigned (  NOT A )    WHEN "011",
                    a_unsig SLL 1          WHEN "100",
                    a_unsig ROL 1          WHEN "101",
                    a_unsig SRL 1          WHEN "110",
                    a_unsig ROR 1          WHEN OTHERS;

  ---------- Arithmetic Unic:---------- ( signed for calcualtions with integers )
  a_sig <= SIGNED(A);
  b_sig <= SIGNED(B);
  carry <= 1 WHEN Setflag = '1' Else 0;

  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_sig <=     "0000"         WHEN "000",
                a_sig           WHEN "001",
                a_sig + 1   WHEN "010",
                a_sig - 1   WHEN "011",
                a_sig + b_sig   WHEN "100",
                a_sig + b_sig + carry   WHEN "101",
                a_sig - b_sig       WHEN "110",
                a_sig - b_sig - carry   WHEN OTHERS;

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WITH functions(3) SELECT
        c <=    std_logic_vector(c_unsig) WHEN '1',
                STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_sig)   WHEN OTHERS;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

And this entails one more type conversion.

**Changing the type of c_unsig and adding b_unsig:**

```
  SIGNAL c_unsig: unsigned(n-1 downto 0); -- STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL carry: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 1; 
  SIGNAL a_unsig: UNSIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
  signal b_unsig: unsigned(n-1 downto 0);

BEGIN
  a_unsig <= UNSIGNED(A);
  b_unsig <= unsigned(B);

  ---------Logic Unit----------- ( with unsigned output for logic, bitwise operators )
  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_unsig <=      a_unsig AND b_unsig     WHEN "000",
                    a_unsig OR  b_unsig     WHEN "001",
                    a_unsig XOR b_unsig     WHEN "010",
                      NOT a_unsig           WHEN "011",
                    a_unsig SLL 1           WHEN "100",
                    a_unsig ROL 1           WHEN "101",
                    a_unsig SRL 1           WHEN "110",
                    a_unsig ROR 1           WHEN OTHERS;

  ---------- Arithmetic Unic:---------- ( signed for calcualtions with integers )
  a_sig <= SIGNED(A);
  b_sig <= SIGNED(B);
  carry <= 1 WHEN Setflag = '1' Else 0;

  WITH functions(2 DOWNTO 0) SELECT
    c_sig <=     "0000"         WHEN "000",
                a_sig           WHEN "001",
                a_sig + 1   WHEN "010",
                a_sig - 1   WHEN "011",
                a_sig + b_sig   WHEN "100",
                a_sig + b_sig + carry   WHEN "101",
                a_sig - b_sig       WHEN "110",
                a_sig - b_sig - carry   WHEN OTHERS;

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WITH functions(3) SELECT
        c <=    std_logic_vector(c_unsig) WHEN '1',
                STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_sig) WHEN OTHERS;
```

This matches your usage for signed operation.

All three changes analyze and elaborate. Without a testbench to generate `clock` and the various other inputs, bounds checking hasn't been verified.

This code does not rely on -2008.

VHDL is a strongly typed language and functions implementing operators are made eligible for operator overloading based on signatures specifying both input types *and* the return type.

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.5.2 Operator overloading, 4.5.3 Signatures, 9.2 Operators, 9.3.6 Type conversions and 12.5 The context of overload resolution.